# App Open Ads issue .How to Hide from splash screen in react native...?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I am use App Open Ads Manager class. Its java class that shows ads whenever app open from Background. Now I want to hide ads in splash screen .If I can get route name in App Open Ads Manager class then its possible or if any other solution.

Comment: Which package are you using for this, does react-native-admob support it??